# Multiline ssh command with for

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc

I'm having a `bash` script that is executing commands through `ssh`.

```
FILENAMES=(
  "export_production_20200604.tgz"
  "export_production_log_20200604.tgz"
  "export_production_session_20200604.tgz"
  "export_production_view_20200604.tgz"
)

sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -T $LOGIN@$IP '/bin/bash' <<EOF
  for f in "${FILENAMES[@]}"; do
    echo Untar "$f"
  done
EOF
```

The thing is when I execute the script, `$f` is empty.

I've looked at multiple solutions online to perform multiple command executions, but none works :

[link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496171/how-to-execute-multiple-lines-of-code-inside-ssh-in-bash-script)

[link 2](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-ssh-run-command-on-remote-machine-server/)

...

Could you help me figure it out ?

---

**Note** :

The execution of :

```
for f in "${FILENAMES[@]}"; do
    echo Untar "$f"
done
```

outside the `<<EOF` `EOF`, works

---

**On local :**

bash 4.4.20(1)-release

**Remote :**

bash 4.2.46(2)-release

---

---

**EDIT : Tricks**

Having a tight timeline, and having no choice, I implemented the solution provided by @hads0m, may it helps fellow developer having the same issue :

```
# $1 the command
function executeRemoteCommand() {
    sshpass -p $DB_PASSWORD ssh $DB_LOGIN@$DB_SERVER_IP $1
}

for i in "${!FILENAMES[@]}"; do
    f=$FILENAMES[$i]

    DB_NAME=$DB_NAMES[$i]

    # Untar the file
    executeRemoteCommand '/usr/bin/tar xzvf '$MONGODB_DATA_PATH'/'$TMP_DIRECTORY'/'$f' --strip-components=1'

    # Delete the tar
    executeRemoteCommand 'rm -f '$MONGODB_DATA_PATH'/'$TMP_DIRECTORY'/'$f''

    # Restore the database
    executeRemoteCommand 'mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1:'$DB_PORT' --username "'$MONGODB_USER'" --password "'$MONGODB_PASSWORD'" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip "'$DB_NAME'" --db "'$DB_NAME'"'
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape $ sign to avoid it being expanded locally and pass the array to remote.

This may be what you wanted :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILENAMES=(
      "export_production_20200604.tgz"
      "export_production_log_20200604.tgz"
      "export_production_session_20200604.tgz"
      "export_production_view_20200604.tgz"
)

sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -T $LOGIN@$IP '/bin/bash' <<EOF
  $(declare -p FILENAMES)                                                                       
  for f in "\${FILENAMES[@]}"; do                                                               
    echo Untar "\$f"                                                                            
  done                                                                                          
EOF
```

Comment: You do need to escape `$FILENAMES`. Try and you will find out.

Comment: In addition to your answer : If you want to declare more than one variable, the syntax is : `$(declare -p FILENAMES MONGODB_DATA_PATH TMP_DIRECTORY DB_PORT MONGODB_USER MONGODB_PASSWORD FILE_EXT)`

Comment: Yes I do :) My script is quite long. I just pointed out the main issue with a small sample for the readability of the question.

Comment: In that case, maybe try to find a way where quoting is not needed, as too much quoting makes code difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it like this:

```
for f in "${FILENAMES[@]}"; do
  sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh -T $LOGIN@$IP echo Untar "$f"
done
```

Also, don't forget to add `#!/bin/bash` into the first line of your script.

Comment: The code I've shown is an extract of a specific part of my script. I have correctly setted up the shebang. About your soluce, I would rather have one ssh connection to be opened rather than X.

Comment: Having no other soluce for now, I've used your syntax. Still waiting for an answer allowing me to execute multiple remote command at once. Thanks for your input.